# Probablity - Calculate $E\left[X^2\right]$ using MGF

Tags: probability

i know that $X\:\:U\left(\:r\:\:,\:-r\right)\:\:\:\:0<r<\sqrt{3}$.
So, want to Calculate $E\left[X^2\right]$ using  MGF. I know that MGF of discrete uniform random variable is $M_{x\left(t\right)}\:=\:\:\:\frac{e^{rt}-e^{-rt}}{t\left(2r\right)}$.
Without using $var$ or something else, only MGF, how to prove its equal to $E\left[X^2\right]\:=\:\frac{\:\:\left(2r\right)^2}{12}$?

Comment: Do you know the definition of the MGF? What happens when you differentiate it?

Answer (score 0):

Given that $r \in (0, \sqrt{3})$ it seems reasonable that $X$ is a continuous random variable rather than a discrete one.  So if we wish to calculate the MGF of a continuous distribution with support $-r < X < r$, we would need to write $$M_X(t) = \operatorname{E}[e^{tX}] = \int_{x=-r}^r e^{tx} \frac{1}{2r} \, dx,$$ since the density of $X$ is $$f_X(x) = \begin{cases} \frac{1}{2r}, & -r < x < r, \\ 0, & \text{otherwise}. \end{cases}$$  Thus we have $$M_X(t) = \frac{1}{2tr} \left[ e^{tx} \right]_{x=-r}^r = \frac{e^{rt} - e^{-rt}}{2rt}.$$  Now, as a function of $t$, the MGF has the property that $$\operatorname{E}[X^k] = \frac{d}{dt^k} \left[M_X(t) \right]_{t=0};$$ that is, the $k^{\rm th}$ raw moment of $X$ is equal to the $k^{\rm th}$ derivative of the MGF evaluated at $t = 0$, provided that the moment is defined and the MGF exists in a neighborhood of zero.

So, what you need to do is calculate the second derivative and then plug in $t = 0$, which should give you the desired result.  I will leave this as an exercise.

Comment: first of all thanks. the MGF of discrete or continuous (for uniform) is the same, but i get troubled in the second derivative. i get i need to divide with zero!

Comment: In fact, the MGF for a discrete uniform distribution is not the same as the continuous one:  the one that you wrote is for a *continuous* uniform distribution.  For a discrete distribution that takes on values in $\{0, \pm 1, \pm 2, \ldots, \pm r\}$, $$M_X(t) = \sum_{x=-r}^r \frac{e^{xt}}{2r} = \frac{e^{(1+r)t} - e^{-rt}}{(2r+1)(e^t - 1)}.$$  As for calculating the second derivative and evaluating it at $t = 0$, you will need to take a limit to do this.  But this is what you are requested to do by the problem, even though it is easier to calculate $\operatorname{E}[X^2]$ directly.